# QuickFIX C++ - No response for MarketDataRequest from the server

Tags: c++, windows, algorithmic-trading, quickfix, fix-protocol

I'm new to FIX protocol and QuickFIX. After I was able to successfully run the `tradingclient` example from the official QuickFIX repo, I tried building my own class (initiator). Everything seems to go well up until I send a `MarketDataRequest` to the server. After that, there's no response from the server. No exceptions either.

I know my configuration file is correct, since the official example works and returns market data with the same configuration file. The connection is also intact, since I could see the heartbeat coming through at the specified interval. What might I be doing wrong?

Here's my class header file - `FIXTrader.h`

```
#pragma once

#include <quickfix/Session.h>
#include <quickfix/MessageCracker.h>
#include <quickfix/Values.h>
#include <quickfix/Mutex.h>

#include <quickfix/fix43/MarketDataRequest.h>

#include <queue>

namespace FIX
{
    class FIXTrader: public Application, MessageCracker
    {
    public:
        virtual ~FIXTrader() {};
        void run();

    private:

        void onCreate(const SessionID&);
        void onLogon(const SessionID&);
        void onLogout(const SessionID&);
        void toAdmin(Message&, const SessionID&);
        void toApp(Message&, const SessionID&)
            throw(DoNotSend);
        void fromAdmin(const Message&, const SessionID&)
            throw(FieldNotFound, IncorrectDataFormat, IncorrectTagValue, RejectLogon);
        void fromApp(const Message&, const SessionID&)
            throw(FieldNotFound, IncorrectDataFormat, IncorrectTagValue, UnsupportedMessageType);

        void onMessage(const FIX43::ExecutionReport&, const FIX::SessionID&);
        void onMessage(const FIX43::OrderCancelReject&, const FIX::SessionID&);
        void onMessage(const FIX43::MarketDataRequest&, const FIX::SessionID&);
        void onMessage(const FIX43::MarketDataRequestReject&, const FIX::SessionID&);

        FIX43::MarketDataRequest queryMarketDataRequest43();

        void queryHeader(FIX::Header& header);
    };
}

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
```

Here are the relevant parts of my `FIXTrader.cpp` (I'm willing to add more if necessary):

```
void FIX::FIXTrader::onMessage
(const FIX43::ExecutionReport&, const FIX::SessionID&) {}
void FIX::FIXTrader::onMessage
(const FIX43::OrderCancelReject&, const FIX::SessionID&) {}
void FIX::FIXTrader::onMessage
(const FIX43::MarketDataRequest&, const FIX::SessionID&)
{
    std::cout << "request success" << std::endl;
}
void FIX::FIXTrader::onMessage
(const FIX43::MarketDataRequestReject&, const FIX::SessionID&)
{
    std::cout << "request rejected" << std::endl;
}


FIX43::MarketDataRequest FIX::FIXTrader::queryMarketDataRequest43()
{
    FIX::MDReqID mdReqID("MARKETDATAID");
    FIX::SubscriptionRequestType subType(FIX::SubscriptionRequestType_SNAPSHOT_PLUS_UPDATES);
    FIX::MarketDepth marketDepth(0);

    FIX43::MarketDataRequest::NoMDEntryTypes marketDataEntryGroup;
    FIX::MDEntryType mdEntryType(FIX::MDEntryType_BID);
    marketDataEntryGroup.set(mdEntryType);

    FIX43::MarketDataRequest::NoRelatedSym symbolGroup;
    FIX::Symbol symbol("EURUSD.x");
    symbolGroup.set(symbol);

    FIX43::MarketDataRequest message(mdReqID, subType, marketDepth);
    message.addGroup(marketDataEntryGroup);
    message.addGroup(symbolGroup);

    queryHeader(message.getHeader());

    std::cout << message.toXML() << std::endl;
    std::cout << message.toString() << std::endl;

    return message;
}

void FIX::FIXTrader::run()
{
    try
    {
        FIX::Message md = queryMarketDataRequest43();
        std::cout << "Sending marketrequest" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "sendToTarget() => " << FIX::Session::sendToTarget(md) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Sent marketrequest" << std::endl;
        while (_getwch() != 126);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Message Not Sent: " << e.what();
    }
}
```

And here's my `main` function:

```
#include "FixTrader.h"
#include <quickfix/FileStore.h>
#include <quickfix/FileLog.h>
#include <quickfix/SocketInitiator.h>
#include <quickfix/SessionSettings.h>
#include <quickfix/config.h>

// #include "quickfix/Application.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        if (argc < 2) return 1;
        std::string fileName = argv[1];

        FIX::SessionSettings settings(fileName);

        FIX::FIXTrader trader_app;
        FIX::FileStoreFactory storeFactory(settings);
        FIX::FileLogFactory logFactory(settings);
        FIX::SocketInitiator initiator
        (trader_app, storeFactory, settings, logFactory /*optional*/);
        initiator.start();
        trader_app.run();
        initiator.stop();
        return 0;
    }
    catch (FIX::ConfigError& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what();
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Here's the output when I try to run the build:

```
C:\fix_trader\Release>fix_trader.exe configfile.txt
<message>
<header>
<field number="8"><![CDATA[FIX.4.3]]></field>
<field number="35"><![CDATA[V]]></field>
<field number="49"><![CDATA[***]]></field>
<field number="56"><![CDATA[****]]></field>
</header>
<body>
<field number="146"><![CDATA[1]]></field>
<field number="262"><![CDATA[MARKETDATAID]]></field>
<field number="263"><![CDATA[1]]></field>
<field number="264"><![CDATA[0]]></field>
<field number="267"><![CDATA[1]]></field>
<group>
<field number="55"><![CDATA[EURUSD.x]]></field>
</group>
<group>
<field number="269"><![CDATA[0]]></field>
</group>
</body>
<trailer>
</trailer>
</message>
8=FIX.4.3 9=79 35=V 49=*** 56=**** 146=1 55=EURUSD.x 262=MARKETDATAID 263=1 264=0 267=1 269=0 10=223 
Sending marketrequest
OUT: 8=FIX.4.3 9=109 35=V 34=5 49=*** 52=20220924-07:35:58.000 56=**** 146=1 55=EURUSD.x 262=MARKETDATAID 263=1 264=0 267=1 269=0 10=184 
sendToTarget() => 1
Sent marketrequest
fromAdmin: 8=FIX.4.3 9=62 35=A 34=1 49=**** 52=20220924-07:35:58.404 56=*** 98=0 108=30 10=234 
Logon successful! Session ID: FIX.4.3:***->****
fromAdmin: 8=FIX.4.3 9=50 35=0 34=2 49=**** 52=20220924-07:36:28.662 56=*** 10=194 
fromAdmin: 8=FIX.4.3 9=50 35=0 34=3 49=**** 52=20220924-07:36:58.682 56=*** 10=200 
fromAdmin: 8=FIX.4.3 9=50 35=5 34=4 49=**** 52=20220924-07:37:06.188 56=*** 10=201 
Logged out from session: FIX.4.3:***->****
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might not be getting a response from them?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for the much delayed reply, I've been caught up in a different project and only revisiting this today. Well, I *am* getting a successful login (and logout) response, so the connection is good, and the server is able to respond to my requests. If the message was malformed, I should at least be getting some kind of reject message, which doesn't happen either. The MarketDataRequest also does not require an SSL connection, so I see no reason for not getting a response for this request alone.

Comment: Ask your counter party why they are not responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out why it wasn't working. It is a silly mistake once the understanding came.

I just needed to include `MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh` (or whatever snapshot type I'm requesting), and overload the `onMessage` callback method appropriately.

Sharing here for anyone who might find this helpful in future.

```
#pragma once

// Other includes here
// ...
// ...
#include <quickfix/fix43/MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh.h>

namespace FIX
{
    class FIXTrader: public Application, MessageCracker
    {
    public:
        virtual ~FIXTrader() {};
        void run();

    private:

        // Other member methods and overloads here
        // ...
        // ...
        void onMessage(const FIX43::MarketDataRequest&, const FIX::SessionID&);
        void onMessage(const FIX43::MarketDataRequestReject&, const FIX::SessionID&);
        void onMessage(const FIX43::MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh&, const FIX::SessionID&);
    };
}

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
```

Since I was missing the overload, it looks like the response ticks from the counterparty was just disappearing into the void. Now the overloaded function captures the market data and sends it to my `fromApp` callback.

Answer (score 0):

**Why it is not working?**

You are sending the MarketDataRequest before being actually connected logically to the counter party Session.
Notice that your message was sent at 07:35:58:000 but your FIXSession connected 404 milliseconds later: 07:35:48.404.

Despite the fact the socket is connected, you are not connected logically (fix-protocol) to the counter party until both sides exchange a 35=A (LOGON message). *You might find the details here: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/fix-protocol-session-or-admin-messages.html#axzz7jSDzNMdi*

**That is the reason the counter party did not receive your Market Data Request.**

```
35=V 52=20220924-07:35:58.000
35=A 52=20220924-07:35:58.404
```

**Your Market Data Request**

```
8=FIX.4.3 9=109 35=V 34=5 49=X 52=20220924-07:35:58.000 56=X 146=1 55=EURUSD.x 262=MARKETDATAID 263=1 264=0 267=1 269=0 10=184
```

**The counter party confirming the LOGON/connection** at the 404 millisecond after you get connected logically. Then, you sent and receive a 35=0, HeartBeat.

```
8=FIX.4.3 9=62 35=A 34=1 49=X 52=20220924-07:35:58.404 56=X 98=0 108=30 10=234
Logon successful! Session ID: FIX.4.3:A->A
fromAdmin: 8=FIX.4.3 9=50 35=0 34=2 49=X 52=20220924-07:36:28.662 56=X 10=194 
fromAdmin: 8=FIX.4.3 9=50 35=0 34=3 49=X 52=20220924-07:36:58.682 56=X 10=200
```

**Then, the counter party sent a LOGOUT request**, to disconnect your app.

```
fromAdmin: 8=FIX.4.3 9=50 35=5 34=4 49=X 52=20220924-07:37:06.188 56=X 10=201 
Logged out from session: FIX.4.3:X->X
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I did try letting the application `Sleep` for a second after sending out the login request and before the `applicaton.run()` call, but that did not fix the issue either. Not the version I shared here of course, but I made sure that I got a login response before sending out the MarketDataRequest.

Comment: Even if I don't wait for login to complete, the documentation [seems to suggest](https://quickfixengine.org/c/documentation/#item-creating-your-application-1) that "If no one is logged on, the messages will be sent at the time a connection is established with the counterparty."

Comment: What FIX library are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry, do you mean the FIX engine or dictionary/version that I'm using?